# Cookies are not saved while using LWP::UserAgent

Tags: perl, cookies, lwp-useragent

I'm trying to use cookies with `LWP::UserAgent` but they are not being saved in the text file. What am I doing wrong?

```
use v5.16;
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

use LWP::UserAgent;
use HTTP::Cookies;
use Net::SSL ();

my $cookie_jar = HTTP::Cookies->new( 
    file => 'lwp_cookies.txt',
    autosave => 1,
);

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new(
    ssl_opts   => { verify_hostname => 0 },
    cookie_jar => $cookie_jar,
);

my $auth_url = 'https://my.site.url/path/authenticate';
use HTTP::Request::Common qw(GET);
my $req = HTTP::Request->new(GET => $auth_url);
$req->authorization_basic('username', 'password');

$ua->request($req);
say Dumper( \$cookie_jar );
```

And the dumped data looks like this:

```
$VAR1 = \bless( {
   'autosave' => 1,
   'COOKIES' => {
          'my.site.url' => {
                '/' => {
                     'BLAH_COOKIE_KEY' => [
                         0,
                         'very_long_string',
                         undef,
                         1,
                         undef,
                         undef,
                         1
                       ]
                   }
              }
        },
   'file' => 'lwp_cookies.txt'
 }, 'HTTP::Cookies' );
```

And `lwp_cookies.txt` just has this:

```
#LWP-Cookies-1.0
```

I'm on Win with Strawberry Perl.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try issuing a:

```
$cookie_jar->save
```

Also, the cookies might be expired, or requested to be discarded, so, also, construct your `$cookie_jar` with `ignore_discard` set to 1:

```
my $cookie_jar = HTTP::Cookies->new( 
    file => 'lwp_cookies.txt',
    autosave => 1,
    ignore_discard => 1,
);
```